# React Hook useEffect async fetch data not passing to tooltip material ui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, frontend

I want passing data after fetching that with use effect into my component, after a while i found the problem

### Here some of my code

### userData Types (UPDATED)

```
export interface IUser {

display_name:  string;
  id:            string;
  images:        Image[];
}

export interface Image {
  url:    string;
}
```

### UseState (UPDATED)

```
const [userData, setUser] = React.useState<IUser[]>([{
display_name: '',
id: '',
images: [{
  url: ''
}]

}]);

const token = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.token.value);
```

### GetCurrentUser function

```
const getCurrentUser = async (token: string) => {
try {
  const response = await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }

  })
  return response.data
}
catch (e) {

  console.error(e)
}


}
```

### useEffect function

i use async

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const get = async()=>{
  const data = await getCurrentUser(token);
  setUser(data)
}
get();

},[])
```

### My main component

im using app bar component template from material ui and the problem come from tooltip child component that show avatar

here my code

```
...
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'end' }}>
        {console.log(userData)} //this line working and can pass the data
        <Tooltip title={userData.images[0].url}> // this line didnt working so if i pass to another child like avatar it cant work too, but if i delete the data code it will work properly
          <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
            {/* {console.log(userData.images[0].url)} */}
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src='{}' />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
...
</Box>
...
```

### The Error

[image]

i think the problem come from rendering react, because in the outside of tooltips component it can work but when enter the tooltip component it will render tooltips component first before the useEffect so the data is unavailable

Im stuck for my final project to show profile data in app bar because i cant resolve this problem :V so can anyone help me for this ?? big thanks!

Comment: What is `userData`, an array or an object? Can you provide an example value? The issue is that on the initial render `userData` is empty, so trying to access into an undefined property throws that error.

Comment: @DrewReese its an array of object, should i define the type of userData first? im get userData from spotify api, so i didnt define that first

Comment: Ok, then there may be an issue with this access `userData.images[0].url`. Yes, please share the `userData` value. And yes, you probably should defined a type for it, type `any` doesn't help you much.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added the userData type and initial value, it still shows the same error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'display_name')"

Comment: Ok, but you've still declared the `userData` state value as an array but then access it like an object in your render. Did you really intend to do something more like `userData[0].images[0].url` instead?

Comment: @DrewReese its work but i define userData as an object, typescript show an error if i define it as a array of object thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you've declared `userData` to be an array.

```
export interface IUser {
  display_name: string;
  id: string;
  images: Image[];
}

export interface Image {
  url: string;
}
```

...

```
const [userData, setUser] = React.useState<IUser[]>([{
  display_name: '',
  id: '',
  images: [{ url: '' }],
}]);
```

In the render return the code is accessing the `userData` state as though it was an object. `console.log(userData)` is ok since it's just the entire state value, but `userData.images` is undefined. Accessing `userData.images` alone is ok though, it's when the code then attempts to access the 0th index of this undefined value that the error is thrown.

I suspect you meant to access `userData[0].images` first, then `userData[0].images[0]`.

code

```
console.log(userData);

...
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'end' }}>
  <Tooltip title={userData[0].images[0].url}>
    <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
      <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src='{}' />
    </IconButton>
  </Tooltip>
  ...
</Box>
...
```